# Exception basics: why is the while loop turning into an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    int x;
    int y = 1;
    while(x != y){
        std::cout << "Please, enter 1." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> x;
        try{
            if(x != y){
            throw 2;
           }
        }
        catch(int){
            std::cout << "You didn't enter 1." << std::endl;
        }
    }
    if(x == 1){
        std::cout << "Well done." << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I provide 1 as input, it works nicely, outputting the message "Well done" as intended. However, when I provide *cin* with any other kind of input, the code produces a loop that prints out the message "You didn't enter 1" indefinitely. I'd like to know why that's happening.

Comment: The stuff you gave cin which it can't read. Where does it go, do you reckon?

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info, so `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your program

Comment: `x` is used before initialization. The behavior is undefined.

Comment: Never throw anything which does not derive from `std::exception`.

Answer (score 1):

After you give non integer value of x,

```
cin >> x
```

cin goes into error state and can not read further.. so loop continue as there is no stoppage except statement containing cin.